# Multiple Apollo queries in one component, getting cannot redeclare block-scoped variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have these two Apollo queries in one React component:

```
 const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(PlaylistQuery, {
    variables: { _id: playlistId },
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
  });

  const [loadSong, { called, loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(SongQuery, {
    variables: {
      _id: song._id,
    },
  });
```

This will obviously give me this error message:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable
```

What's a smart way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid this issue, you could simply rename your queries' variables. As an example, like below:

```js
const {
  data: playListData,
  loading: playListLoading,
  error: playListError,
} = useQuery(PlaylistQuery, {
  variables: { _id: playlistId },
  fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
});

const [
  loadSong,
  { called: songFuctionCalled, loading: songLoading, error: songError, data: songData },
] = useLazyQuery(SongQuery, {
  variables: {
    _id: song._id,
  },
});
```